# Getting the class of an object

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to know if it's possible to do the following. I need to pass some objects over tcp. I choose to convert them to JSON using Gson. But this  objects can have different types. Mainly i have:

```
public class NetMessage {
    public int code;
    public Object obj;
}
```

there is the `code` and an object it can have  different class types. How can I rebuild my object after transfer to it's initial type?

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gsonizer gs = new Gsonizer();
    Invoice v = new Invoice(123, 123, 10.1);
    NetMessage nm = new NetMessage(2, v);
    String s = (String) gs.toNet(nm);
    NetMessage nm2 = (NetMessage) gs.fromNet(s);

    System.out.println("> " +nm2.code);
    System.out.println("> " +(Object)nm2.obj.getClass()); <<<<<<<< *

}
```

My `*` marks a totally different type, it's an internal class from Gson lib it prints:
class `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`

Again how could I accomplish that I rebuild the object to it's initial type.

Edit:
Gson  deserialize code:

```
public Object fromNet(String obj){
        return  gsonizer.fromJson(obj, NetMessage.class);
    }
```

Comment: Show us the Gson deserialization code...

Comment: Seems like generics would fit the bill. `NetMessage<M extends MessageClassType>`.

Comment: Is there any reflexion way maybe?

Comment: @aliteralmind unlikely, GSON (the library) still wouldn't know what to deserialize it to.

Comment: @immibis. Right. I read Sotirios Delimanolis' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, with your setup, it's impossible.

Gson performs its deserialization by looking at the target type. It has some defaults for when that type doesn't matter. In the case of `Object`, that type is `LinkedTreeMap`.

Given

```
public class NetMessage {
    public int code;
    public Object obj;
}
```

and

```
return  gsonizer.fromJson(obj, NetMessage.class);
```

you haven't specified how `obj` field should be deserialized. In this case, Gson will use a `LinkedTreeMap` by default.

The only solution is to explicitly specify the type you want for `obj`.

Comment: What if I add type as String in my NM object which contains class name? Ty by the way for the insight about the default class thingie

Comment: @BogdanM. I don't believe Gson has a built-in feature for that. You should look into that. Other JSON parsers _do_ exist that can deserialize based on a `class` field in the JSON.